# Page Will Not Expand with DIV

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a page that will resize with my main `content` div. Currently, when I set my `content` div to `height: 1000px`, it runs over my footer divs. How do I change this so that it expands with my `content` div?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Layout</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/layout.css">
</head>
    <body>
    <div class="top">
    </div>
        <div class="left">

        </div>
        <div class="right">

            <div class="content">
                <h1>Page Content</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="preFooter">

        </div>
        <div class="myFooter">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;

    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

html,body { height:100%; }

h1{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}

.left{
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #757475;
    height: 100%;
}

.right{
    float: right;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #e9eaed;
    height: 100%;
}

.top{
    overflow : hidden;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: #333333;
    width: 100%;
}

.preFooter{
    overflow : hidden;
    height: 20%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
}

.myFooter{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 40%;
    background-color: #333333;
    width: 100%;
}

.content{
    margin-top: 5%;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: white;
    height: 1000px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set a height to `.left` and `.right`. This way the contents will decide how tall to make an element.

[Here's a JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/mqxy1zvp/3/)

The reason it doesn't fill up the entire height of the page is because other elements on the page (the content div) have a fixed height set to 1000 pixels. You'd also have to do what Rob said and use a clearfix, or drop floats all together and use flexbox, which is new and great! See the second link below:

[Here's another. I started this from scratch, maybe it will seem more straight forward this way.](https://jsfiddle.net/zo6j7o54/1/)

Comment: how would I add a background-color to the `.right` div? I have a color assigned, but this doesn't work.

Comment: the background-color for `.rigtht` only goes about 3/4 of the way down.

Comment: The easiest way I can think of would be to set it's position to fixed and to set it's height with viewport units instead. Height's set in percentages takes some trickery, and if you're just learning, it's best to just use them to begin with. Check the fiddle again, i updated it.

Comment: Also, keep in mind what Rob said about using floats. Again, if you're learning, you might want to just ditch floats and learn how to use flexbox instead.

Comment: Okay, thanks.... Could you post the new link, I don't see the update on jsFiddle.

Comment: hmmm... I wonder why the background color in the left div doesn't fill the entire div. If you scroll down, it finished before the pre-footer div.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, this makes so much more sense!!

Answer (score 2):

Your containing element for `.content` is `.right` which is floated. Floated elements are never contained by their parent elements. That is why it expands beyond the bottom of the element.